# require to execute a script in between a test case

Tags: ruby-on-rails, automated-tests, watir

I have a scenario where, I have a RoR application, mysql, and there is a workflow, where

- end user will follow that workflow, and register her software
- software is local to end user, running on her machine
- in between this workflow, I make a http request to this software and it responds back
- this hand shaking take place between rails app and that software
- updating a couple of entries in db
- and now I have to write a test case for this
- that after this workflow done,

  - proper entries are been added to db
  - checking whether workflow is executed successfully
  - plus hand shaking took place well, so a complete cycle
- And Am looking for a best approach here to go with

For now, we do not have prepared, or planning for a nice way of testing entire app here, but just preparing a few important test cases only. And this one is the first one of this kind. So far we were doing it manually.

Now being lazy, we want to automate this, and I am thinking of using watir. I have a software simulator for hand shaking, I could execute that simulator in watir and get this whole cycle tested.

Does this sound good that my watir/rb script is

- executing a script
- checking db status
- executing workflow
- stopping that script
- checking for db status

But obvious all ruby/rails units involved here would have their own unit test cases prepared apart, but I am interested in testing this whole cycle.

Any better suggestions, comments?

Answer (score 0):

It's important to have tests at the unit *AND* functional level, IMO, so I think your general approach is good.

Watir, or Selenium/WebDriver would be good tools to use. If you don't already have an approach in mind, you should check out Cheezy's (Jeff Morgan's) [page-object gem](https://github.com/cheezy/page-object).  It works with Watir-webdriver and Selenium-webdriver.

I like that you explicitly call out hitting the database to check for proper record creation. It's really important to hit the DB as a [test oracle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oracle_%28software_testing%29) to ensure your system's working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't want to start a philosophical debate, but I'll say that going down the road you're thinking has been a time killer for me in the past. I'd strongly recommend spending the time refactoring your code into a structure that can be unit tested. One of the truly nice side effects of focusing on unit tests is that you end of creating a code base that follows the [Principle of Single Responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), whether you realize it or not.

Also, consider skimming [this debate about the fallacies of higher-level testing frameworks](http://www.rubyinside.com/dhh-offended-by-rspec-debate-4610.html)

Anyway, good luck, friend.

Comment: you said it "killer for me in the past", could you please make me realize how bad it was, a couple of major cases would do.

Comment: I was developing a rather small app, to manage listings of phone nums and addresses, that had maybe 8 screens with ~20 tables. We used a lot of Ajax (another dubious choice) and quite a bit of client-side js to provide a rich client interface. Because of this, it seemed to me at the time that browser-based testing made sense, given the amount of client-side business logic. What I ended up with was the app itself, and really a second app, the Selenium tests, for which I spent nearly as much time fixing Selenium tests as I did the actual app.